# How to force iframe video to rotate to landscape mode on android devices?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

How can I force to rotate a video to landscape mode programmatically on android devices like it does on iOS devices when the video is played?

I am using cordova application and here is the code on the HTML view:

```
<iframe style="width:100%;height:100%" ng-src="{{videoUrl}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Screen Orientation plugin](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-screen-orientation/). With this plugin installed, you can set screen orientation programmatically.  All you need to do is to attach event listeners for starting and stopping the video and then you can do something like `window.screen.orientation.lock('landscape')` when the playback starts and `window.orientation.unlock()` when the playback stops.